# Grouping to only remove NULLs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, null, aggregate-functions

I've got a table as follows, that has rooms, time slots, and students in that room per time slot

```
Room       <10:00     10:00 - 14:00     14:00+
101        Sally      NULL              NULL
101        Jeremy     NULL              NULL
101        Rick       NULL              NULL
101        NULL       Jeremy            NULL
101        NULL       Mark              NULL
101        NULL       NULL              Steve
101        NULL       NULL              Brandon
101        NULL       NULL              Lily
101        NULL       NULL              Debbie
201        Nancy      NULL              NULL
201        NULL       Frank             NULL
201        NULL       NULL              Steve
201        NULL       NULL              Claudette
301        NULL       George            NULL
301        Jake       NULL              NULL
```

The output desired is would look like like the following:

```
Room       <10:00     10:00 - 14:00     14:00+
101        Sally      Jeremy            Steve
101        Jeremy     Mark              Brandon
101        Rick                         Lily
101                                     Debbie
201        Nancy      Frank             Steve
201                                     Claudette
301        Jake       George
```

Feel free to assume that there are many more rooms as well as names and time slots per room. This is just a small sample to work with.

The goal here is to remove all the NULLS, or at least reduce where they're not needed, and push the data up and fill the spaces where applicable in a room.

If it weren't for the fact that each time slot needed it's own line per student name, I'd have just used an aggregate function and concatenated them all together as such

```
select 

Room
,string_agg('<10:00', '; ') as '<10:00'
,string_agg('10:00 - 14:00', '; ') as '10:00 - 14:00'
,string_agg('14:00+', '; ') as '14:00+'

from room_time_slots

group by room
```

Which would create this:

```
Room       <10:00                10:00 - 14:00     14:00+
101        Sally; Jeremy; Rick   Jeremy; Mark      Steve; Brandon; Lily; Debbie
201        Nancy                 Frank             Steve; Claudette
301        Jake                  George
```

But it is insisted that each student must have their own line, so the above isn't being accepted.

I've attempted to create a type of counter to track each time a name is given for a room (per time slot),l and then I'd simply group BY that counter, meaning it would fill the table from the top down. But none of the RANK functions seem to fit what I need. I can't find a good method to create and update a counter in SQL either as my searches only bring me back to the COUNT aggregate functions, which are also not what I need. For that I'd need a counter that would increase each time a new name PER room PER time slot is entered, and then reset back to zero when encountering a new room, which I imagine would work in theory.

Comment: I *really* hope your columns aren't really called `[<10:00]`,`[10:00 - 14:00]`, and `[14:00+]`. if they are, I highly recommend renaming them; you'll come to regret it pretty quickly as they'll pretty difficult names to work with. Try to keep names of columns so that they don't need to be delimit identified. It also, however, seems like the data is denormalised, and the time slot should actually be 2 columns (start and end) with a single column for the name. This also means you don't need DDL changes, if your timeslots change in the future.

Comment: Relax, these are not table column names. I'm simplifying what's going on. This is actually a 'view' that got the data to this point, as the data has been pivoted.

Comment: That's why I said I *hope* they're not, @RallyToMe . :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only one slot is filled in on each row, you can calculate a sequential value, ignoring `null` values.

Then aggregation does what you want:

```
select room, max(slot1), max(slot2), max(slot3)
from (select t.*,
             (case when slot1 is not null
                   then row_number() over (partition by room order by (case when slot1 is not null then 1 else 2 end))
                   when slot2 is not null
                   then row_number() over (partition by room order by (case when slot2 is not null then 1 else 2 end))
                   when slot3 is not null
                   then row_number() over (partition by room order by (case when slot3 is not null then 1 else 2 end))
              end) as seqnum
      from <tablename> t
     ) t
where seqnum is not null
group by room, seqnum;
```

I've replaced the column names with something easier to type.

Comment: slot 1, slot 2, slot 3?

Are those just replacements for the column names I've given?

Comment: You just said those aren't your real column names anyway, @RallyToMe . Gordon wouldn't be so silly to give something a name/alias like that either. ;)

Comment: Am I not allowed to double check?

Comment: @RallyToMe . . . I thought I had already put that in the answer.  Yes, I replaced the column names with something reasonable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff hmm.... havne't been able to get this to work yet. It doesn't like me putting the table name in where you have "from t"

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually had much call (or opportunity) to use full outer joins, so this might not be entirely right, but it seems like something like this would work:

```
SELECT q1.room, f1, f2, f3
FROM (SELECT room, f1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY room ORDER BY f1) AS rowNum WHERE f1 IS NOT NULL ) AS q1
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT room, f2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY room ORDER BY f2) AS rowNum WHERE f2 IS NOT NULL ) AS q2 ON q1.room = q2.room AND q1.rowNum = q2.rowNum
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT room, f3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY room ORDER BY f3) AS rowNum WHERE f3 IS NOT NULL ) AS q2 ON q1.room = q3.room AND q1.rowNum = q3.rowNum
ORDER BY q1.room, q2.room, q3.room
   , q1.rowNum, q2.rowNum, q3.rowNum
;
```

Edit: Similar to Gordon's answer, consider `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` as placeholders for the actual column names.

Also note that this will yield `101|Sally|Jeremy|Brandon` not `101|Sally|Jeremy|Steve` as depite how you have presented them your rows really have no inherent order.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the input, as it helped push me in the direction I took, and I used some of the elements you gave, as I was unable to implement any of your exact answers.

I ended up splitting the elements up and assigning them their own position number (as views, using the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY) etc), then rejoining them with several Full Outer Joins.

It was messy and overly complicated, and very much a crowbar method, but it got the job done. Basically similar to what many of you suggested, but split up into view and rejoined for some ease on my part (though definitely tedious)